# after create a new anaconda envs, matplotlib can't show the figure of code

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, anaconda

this is my first ask question on the here,Please forgive my poor english.
the code just is simple,I can plot it in colab,but in my pycharm it meet the issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61QJx.png)

somrtime, the figure Crash or no response.
Thanks for the kind people who came to save me，I have wasted an afternoon on it.

Comment: Hi tao. Welcome. It would be helpful if you copy/paste the text from that image inside triple quotes (or select and format as code using the `{}`)